# Problem involving explicit solutions for differentials

Tags: calculus

Hi so this is the problem I am trying to work out

> Find an explicit solution for $xy′ = e−y$, for $y(1) = 1$

I worked it through to find the anti-derivative and ended up getting 
y = ln(lnx +C), I went on to find C which was e^1. However I am not too sure if did the anti-derivative correctly and what it means by explicit solution. If anyone can break it down and explain that would be great :).
Thanks

Comment: You did not get the correct answer.  Maybe you would like to show us what you did.  Explicit solution means $y=$ (something involving only $x$).

Comment: Top tip place your final solution back into the original ode to determine if you have found the correct solution.

Comment: Hint: this is an **exact** ODE.

Comment: I think it can also be solved with separation of variables or the homogeneous substitution $u=\frac{y}{x}$

Comment: It is also linear.  Heh...it's like _almost any_ solution technique would work.

Comment: What an interesting differential equation. It can be solved in many different ways

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to put the $y$ on the other side:

$$xy^{\prime}+y=e$$

and then notice that the left side is the product rule for $xy$.

$$(xy)^{\prime} = e$$

So $xy = ex+C$ or $y = e+C/x$.